# Wifi is HardBlocked and i cannot get it up no matter what i do

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, interface

That's my first question and maybe the hardest to answer. I wish you could help me with this matter which is wifi hard Blocked in my Linux machine and can't get the wifi up. The story begin when i have dual booted my windows and **Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS distro** my wifi was working perfectly fine in both OS's idk why but someday my wifi decided to stop in every Linux thing!

When you type the `rfkill list all` command in the terminal you will see response like this

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Here what i did.

I have read every forum in the internet and tried every solution possible for it.

*Like turning off the battery and ac cable.*

*I've also tried to boot other Linux distros with usb bootable iso to see if it's a version issue or not (ParroOS, Debian, arch Linux, core Linux, fedora, LinuxMint and many many more ).*

*Tried to removing the Pin 20 in my wireless card.*

*Tried to BlackList WMI and many more things.*

*Tried to restore the bios settings, it doesn't really have that much of a setting.*

*Tried to removing RF-kill and reinstall it (I Don't know what I'm doing anymore)*

*Tried to turn off the Fast boot setting in windows.*

And nothing have worked!!!

My Device is **Pavilion G6** and wifi card is **Ralink 5390r** (The default manufacture)

Note that the wifi working fine in the windows system and no issues at all.

Please help me with it i really need it and can't afford a new wifi adapter it's too much expensive in my city. Thank you.

Comment: Can you Check in Windows If It is a p

Comment: Hi @nobody i didn't get your request can you give me more information about it?

Comment: Oh i thought i deleted my comment. You Said in Windows WLAN is working. Can you Check in Windows the config's for the Card?

Comment: "`Hard blocked: Yes`" means there's a hardware switch that's disabling WiFi. Search your keyboard for  WiFi symbol. Fn key may be needed.

Comment: Did you put tape on pin 20?  The hybrid shutdown needs to be disabled on Windows

Comment: @waltinator I'm already aware of that, i can change the way of how action keys work from the bios and it doesn't have any relation with the issue.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yessir as I mentioned it before in my question i did both solutions, and nothing worked.

Comment: @nobody in the device manager i right click my wlan card and from properties in the Advance tab there is punch of configurations i think thats the one you wanted?...... ```Adhoc support 802?11n is Disabled ``` and ```Multimedia/Gaming environment is disabled``` and ```radio On/Off is enabled``` let's not forget the ``` Roaming sensitivity is 3.Medium```

Comment: Are there any wifi/wlan settings in BIOS as putting tape on pin 20 should fix anything https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M&ab_channel=SimonHayter

Comment: Nope there isn't any wifi settings in bios, And to be honest with you Mr @Jeremy31 i completely removed the Pin 20 months ago with my steel screw loool it didn't work though idk if putting a duct tape on the the place were pin 20 was should fix my problem but there isn't any problem to try that

Comment: It might be a stopid thing to do but maybe i was in rage at that moment Thats the current situation of it, https://imgur.com/a/TKI1qWy

Comment: I would try some tape there anyhow